# Link maven dependencies on non maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have two projects in Eclipse, the first project depends on maven, the second project which dependent on the first one does NOT depend on maven.

The first project downloads external libraries like jar files and natives to the .m2 maven folder. However the second project gives a ClassNotFoundException since it cant find the jar files and the native files from the first project.

Is it possible to link these downloaded jars+dlls with the second project without having to reference in the **build path->libraries** in the second **project properties**?

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Maven  project, use Assembly  plugin to create  an   Uber-jar  that  contains the  project  build  artifact and all  its dependencies (`mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies`).  Then,  reference that  from  project #2,  either with a  relative path or  by  using an ant build  task to  copy it into your other  project's lib  directory (assuming you have such a  directory).    Also, although  it's  frowned  upon,  you  could  configure the  assembly  plugin so that  your  Uber  jar  artifact always has the  same    `finalName`.

Comment: would this include the dlls? the first project depends on things lwjgl and its natives, or would it be better if i just create a jar-with-dependencies with no dll depedencies and a seperate one? Sorry about all these questions my maven knowledge is almost zero:S

Comment: Yes.  There's a  plugin for that: http://mojo.codehaus.org/maven-native/native-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: thanks i will definitely will have a look at it:) it sounds like a good intermediate step before i change my project to be completely dependent on maven. Thanks @noahz

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to link these downloaded jars+dlls with the second project without having to reference in the build path->libraries in the second project properties?

I don't think so.

But maybe you could create a 3rd project (which is a Maven project) that depends on the first one, and on the JAR (or whatever) file created by the 2nd one as a non-repository dependency.

Having said that, anything you do is going to be a bit of a hack.  You'd be better of either turning the 2nd project into a proper Maven project, or creating a custom build script that manually pulls the 2nd project's dependencies from somewhere.  (I think that Ivy could help you with that ... assuming you use Ant in the 2nd project.)

Comment: The second project is just an eclipse project it doesnt depend on ant builds at all, and the first project depends on a big list of jars, and to be honest i dont have time at all to make the second project a maven project (because my maven skills are almost 0 and because i am very delayed with my actual work in which the second project is on).

Comment: @RicardoDuarte - Well you have to trade-off the time you would spend on fixing the 2nd project to have a proper build setup versus the future / long-term pain (e.g. unreliability, unmaintainability) of the hacks you would otherwise use.  Your choice.

Comment: @RicardoDuarte - *"... because my maven skills are almost 0"*.  Well you know what the solution to that is :-)

Comment: Yes i know what the solution is, i was going to write a maven deployment when the first version was near completion together with a lot cleaning up, i just wanted to know all my solution until i get to that stage. Thanks for your help

Comment: Here's the best resource for beginners: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/